# "Email is Required" validation is not working in bootstrap email box in Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am totally new to Angular and I know I am not the first to ask this ,I am working in an Angular 5 application ,In this I need to validate user mail ,If it is a valid mail I have a button in that button click I need to navigate to new component .

Here pattern validation is working but if I touched the email box but not entered any vales I want to show that "Email is required " but it's not working for me .

And the another thing is I want to make the **"button"** is clickable only after the valid email is entered.

```
<div class="col-12">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" id="email" name="email" ngModel
                #emailref="ngModel">
            <div *ngIf="emailref.errors &&(emailref.touched || emailref.dirty)" class="aler alert-danger">
                <div [hidden]="!emailref.errors?.pattern">
                    Invalid pattern
                </div>
                <div [hidden]="!emailref.errors?.emailref.touched">
                    Invalid pattern
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            <button type="submit" routerLink="/createaccount" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-user text-dark" style="font-size:20px"></i>
                Create An Account
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

can anyone help me solve this .

Comment: I have used the custom implementation to do that.

Comment: I am new to angular ,I couldn't understand what you said ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change in your HTML Markup

```
<div class="col-12">
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" id="email" name="email" ngModel
            #emailref="ngModel" required>
        <div *ngIf="emailref.errors &&(emailref.touched || emailref.dirty)" class="aler alert-danger">
            <div [hidden]="!emailref.errors?.pattern">
                Invalid pattern
            </div>
            <div [hidden]="!emailref.errors?.emailref.touched">
                Email is required
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <button type="submit" routerLink="/createaccount" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="myForm.invalid" >
            <i class="fas fa-user text-dark" style="font-size:20px"></i>
            Create An Account
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Create a reference variable of form as 'myForm' to disable button and Change the content in second valid message

Comment: It showing both validation messages after starting to enter the mail .Once the user starting to enter the mail then it should showing only the "Invalid Pattern" mesage untill the correct pattern is entered by the user @NileshSutar

Comment: And once the valid I entered the valid email format the button is enabled but not get disables if I intentionally clear the entered value. please help me to fix it @ NileshSutar

Comment: And got this error is console "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined" @NileshSutar

Answer (score 0):

You should use ReactiveForms with FormBuilder, then you can set validators like:

```
this.form= this.fb.group({
  'email': new FormControl('', [ Validators.require Validators.email]
 });
```

Read more at official doc, [Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) and [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="emailref.errors && (emailref.touched || emailref.dirty)" class="aler 
      alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="!emailref.invalid?.pattern">
                    Invalid pattern
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="(emailref.touched || emailRef.dirty)">
                    Email is required
                </div>
</div>


    <br>
    <button type="submit" routerLink="/createaccount" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="emailref.invalid" >
        <i class="fas fa-user text-dark" style="font-size:20px"></i>
        Create An Account
    </button>`
```